# AI single document search

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to setup a system where I can undertake a search on a document so that any questions can be answered.  For example, the document may be about visiting a city and include information like key sites and opening times.  The user would be able to ask something like "What are the main places I should visit" or "what are the opening times of the X museum".   The problem with this is that it is all very manual and any errors have to be picked up by me to manually fix. There is always only one document and it can be anything from 5 to 50 pages long.  Does anyone know any AI tools that could help or how I could introduce self learning?

I have achieved this by creating a list of keywords (tags) against key facts.  So the fact could be What are the Museum Opening times? and the keywords Museum and Time.   I then undertake searches using AND and OR functions against the keywords. I have also created a database of pseudonyms e.g. for time I may have opening hours, times of opening etc.

What are the opening times of the X Museum?
The opening times of the museum are Monday to Friday 8am to 8pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an awful lot of detail in your question but it sounds like an application for a chat bot such as ALICE. To create a chat bot for your document you could use AIML.

Here is a tutorial for this :-
https://www.devdungeon.com/content/ai-chat-bot-python-aiml

Noting that I personally have never created such a thing it does seem that the functionality that you require is a good match to this technology.

Comment: Hi Jon.  Thanks - this looks very useful and a perfect match

Comment: If you find an answer useful you should upvote it and possibly accept it. That way other contributors will know the direction of answers most helpful to you.